# C# How check if installed physical memory is either ECC or non-ECC?

Tags: c#, memory, wmi, ram

I'm trying to find out how to check if installed memory (RAM) is ECC of non-ECC
I need to do that with C# using WMI Classes.

Does any of you have an idea ?

thnx in advance

Comment: Tag typed there by accident :O Now removed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could query WMI [`Win32_PhysicalMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394347.aspx) and test whether `TotalWidth` (bit count including any check bits) is greater than `DataWidth` (bit count excluding check bits).

Comment: May I ask what do people get that for ?

Comment: You mean why would they buy ECC? There's a few questions on serverfault e.g. [would you use ECC RAM in a workstation](http://serverfault.com/questions/5817/would-you-use-ecc-ram-in-a-workstation), [what is ECC RAM and why is it better](http://serverfault.com/questions/5887/what-is-ecc-ram-and-why-is-it-better)